# How can i protect parts of code in my Open Source project licensed under GPLv3?

Tags: open-source, obfuscation, source-code-protection

I am creating an Open Source project but I'd like to protect just some parts of my code (mainly these ones related to security). I am using the GPLv3 license. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you're using the GPLv3 license, then the source code must be freely available. Are you intending to separately license this sensitive code?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to split your project up into multiple modules, each of which has a different license. To the best of my knowledge there is nothing preventing a GPLv3 licensed project to use proprietary software. You should however consider using documented interfaces or the equivalent in your programming language of choice so that others who want to reimplement your proprietary code aren't tortured unnecessarily. Ideally you code still compiles but may be limited in or devoid of functionality without that proprietary component.